# how to set facebook plugin in cocos2d-js?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

i am trying to do a facebook integration but it shows me error "ReferenceError: plugin is not defined" then how to set plugin? Here is my line of code

`var facebook = plugin.FacebookAgent.getInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you call the following lines in your AppDelegate. Sometimes you can have a conditional defines around which prevents from their execution. It is useful to put a log message there to make sure it is executed.

```
    sc->addRegisterCallback(register_all_pluginx_protocols);
    sc->addRegisterCallback(register_pluginx_js_extensions);
```

You shall put it right before:

```
sc->addRegisterCallback(JavascriptJavaBridge::_js_register);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `project.json` file you have to include in "module" section like this:

```
"modules": ["pluginx", "plugin-facebook"]
```

in "plugin" section you have to include something like this:

```
"plugin": {  
    "facebook": 
{
      "appId": "FBappID",
      "xfbml": true,
      "version": "FBversion"
    }  
}
```

and in "plugin-facebook": section something like this:

```
"plugin-facebook": [
    "external/pluginx/platform/facebook_sdk.js",
    "external/pluginx/platform/facebook.js"
  ]
```

and in  "pluginx" section:

```
 "pluginx" : [
    "external/pluginx/Plugin.js"
  ]
```